# What could "be followed up" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I received a sentence from a person and the sentence seems grammatically wrong

> sentence: the letter was sent and follow up from the Department to the
>   embassy.

I think the person intended to say "was followed up from ~", so if I regard this sentence like below

> the letter was sent and followed up from the Department to the
>   embassy.

what is the meaning of "be followed up" in the sentence ??

Or maybe the person intended something else using "follow-up" as a single noun in the sentence. How about that ??

Comment: Any chance of a bit more context?

Comment: @dougal ah the person sent me an email and said the letter was sent to the department. I can get that part easily but can not understand 100% since the person made an error. I just assume that it is "be followed up" and would mean "be informed", "be checked", "be recognized", "be noticed", be communicated" or else

Comment: Yes, that is what I would also assume.  However, if this is important perhaps you should go back to the original author and ask for clarification.  Good luck.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical.  It appears to be a kind of short-hand, but even so, the syntax is not valid. Perhaps "... *with* followup from the department".

Comment: Maybe "the letter was sent *as* follow-up..." ? As in, the embassy contacted the Department, the Department answered, they never got any confirmation their answer was received, so they sent a letter *as* follow-up to basically say "hey, did you ever get our response?"

Comment: I agree with @AdamV though I would write "as *a* follow-up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's original form the sentence *is* grammatically wrong.

It could have the following meanings :

- (Someone) tracked the letter sent from the department to the embassy.
- The letter that was sent to the embassy had been acknowledged/recognized.
- The embassy confirms that the letter has been received.
- The embassy has already followed up on the contents of the letter.

These are the ones I can think of. Please check if any of these fits with the rest of the e-mail.